# Convert character variable column to vector

Tags: r, vector, character-encoding

Have a .csv with 4 columns of values:

```
data<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\mtatange\\Desktop\\Dataset.csv")
A         B        C        D   
1         1       NA        1   
2         2        4        1   
3         3        6        4   
4        NA        8        5

data$E<-do.call(paste,c(data[c("A","B","C","D")], sep=""))
data
A         B        C        D       E        
1         1       NA        1      11NA1 
2         2        4        1      2241
3         3        6        4      3364 
4        NA        8        5      4NA85

summary(data)
E
Length: 4
Class: Character
Mode: Character
```

I need column "E" to be a vector, it cannot stay as a character variable. I tried:

```
data$E[is.na(a$E)]<-0
```

But that still left the column as a character variable. How do I convert the column to a vector variable?

Comment: If you replace `NA` to `0` in data (before getting E), then you can do `data$E <- as.numeric(do.call(paste0, data))`

Comment: How would I do that? This is a test example, in the dataset there are 6000 entries.

Comment: do what? replace NA? `data[is.na(data)] <- 0`.

Comment: Sorry I should have clarified, I cannot replace every NA missing value in the entire dataset with O, only this "E" column.

Comment: Mark - why not? 6000 is not very many entries! And it is far quicker to replace NAs in the dataset than it will be to gsub out NA entries in data$E afterwards!

Comment: @MarkT, In that case, after creating `E` the way you've done it... use `data$E <- as.numeric(gsub("NA", "0", data$E))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the NA's first..:

```
df[ is.na(df) ] <- 0
df$E <- apply(df,1,function(x) as.numeric(paste0(x , collapse="")))
  A B C D    E
1 1 1 0 1 1101
2 2 2 4 1 2241
3 3 3 6 4 3364
4 4 0 8 5 4085

apply(df , 2 , class )
        A         B         C         D         E 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"
```

---

The solution above gives you the idea. Alternatively, a (relatively) faster way of doing this is:

```
df[ is.na(df) ] <- 0
df$E <- as.numeric(do.call(paste0, df))
```

And replacement of NA's is very fast. In a test on a 3 column table with 300,000 rows on a MBP laptop...

```
df <- data.frame( a = sample(c(1:9,NA) , 3e5 , repl = TRUE ) , b = sample(c(1:9,NA) , 3e5 , repl = TRUE ) , c = sample(c(1:9,NA) , 3e5 , repl = TRUE )  )   
sum(is.na(df))
[1] 90118

system.time( (df[is.na(df)] <- 0 ) )
  user  system elapsed 
 0.250   0.021   0.269 
nrow(df)
 [1] 300000
```

Comment: SimonO101, `as.numeric(do.call(paste0, df))` would be faster. `apply` converts the `data.frame` to a `matrix`.

Comment: @Arun thank you for the tip. Want to edit it? Or if you write an answer I will just +1 you instead! :-)

Comment: @Arun can you also explain why I don't have to set `collapse = ""` in `do.call` but I do using the `apply` route?

Comment: Simon, can you put down how to replace NA's with 0's only in certain columns? For instance, in column 1-3 I need the NA's but in column 2-5 I need them replaced with 0.

Comment: @SiminO101, iiuc, `collapse` is used when you pass in a single vector and want to stitch them together. ex: `paste(1:5, collapse=".")`. `sep` is used when you've each element passed as a separate argument: ex: `paste(1,2,3,4,5, sep=".")`. The `do.call` syntax basically does the latter but all columns together like: `paste(df$X1, df$X2, sep="")` is equivalent to `do.call(paste0, df[,1:2])`

Comment: Also, why do my other columns in the dataset come up as vector variables even though they have NA in them and my new column created using the do.call function creates a column of character variables?

Comment: @MarkT read the documentation in paste? `paste converts its arguments (via as.character) to character strings, and concatenates them `

Comment: @MarkT, read the help by typing `?NA` (the first paragraph at least).

Comment: `class( c(1,2,3) )` and `class( c(1,2,NA) )` return the same: `"numeric"` - NA is *not available* or missing. A vector may contain missing elements but it may not contain elements of mixed types.  Therefore NA must not change the class of a vector. `class( c( 1, "a") )` returns `"character"` because the 1 has to be converted.

Comment: @Arun thanks, do you know of a function that will concatenate and keep the columns as vectors?